# Reservation of resources in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-calendar, resources

I've followed [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/588685/ReservationplusofplusresourcesplusinplusSharePoint), this not works to me. When I try insert itens on resource list I've the error list not found.

After I added the solution and activate, was created some lists, like:

- Recursos (Resources)
- Memorando de Telefonema (Memorandum of phone call (I guess))
- Group Calendar
- Local (Place)

[image: Lists]

When I click on new event, this option is displayed to me, but the field "Recursos" (Resource) is empty:

[image: Empty resource list]

So, when I try add some Resource by the button "Recurso" (Resource):

[image: Add Resource]

**I've this error:**

[image: Something wrong, list not found]

The error message says:

> #### Something went wrong.
>
> Nonexistent list.
>
> The selected page contains a nonexistent list. She may have been deleted by another user.

I also noticed that the Resources list is called "Instalacoes e Ativos Compartilhados" which means "Facilities and Shared Assets", it should not be named "Resources", "Recursos" or "Facilities"?

[image: Resource list name]

How can I solve this?

Comment: can you paste in english? did you made the changes on web.config file? is it your on prem or sharepoint online?

Comment: yea it is easy to understand the error.

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE I add some infos. Can you help me?

Comment: sandbox solution not deployed sucessfully. i would de activate the feature and reactivitae it.

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE I'd tried this.

Comment: does anyone still have a copy of the calendarwithresources.wps file? the original link does not work any more. would highly aprechiate it if someone could re-up that file!
many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've found the solution for this case, but because I just ran into the very same problem a few minutes ago, here is the solution that worked for me:

1. Open the source code of the calendarwithresources you've downloaded solution in Visual Studio
2. Locate the Schema.xml beneath the Custom List Definition, open the file
3. Locate the Resource List Reference by searching "Lists/Facilities and Shared Assets"
4. Replace the list reference based on your language (it would be "Lists/Instalacoes e Ativos Compartilhados" in your case)
5. Remove all the deployed lists from Site Contents, and redeploy the solution.