# Sharepoint 2013 Search - Missing list. The selected page contains a nonexistent list. It may have been deleted by another user

Tags: search

I'm having a problem with Search in Sharepoint 2013. The scenario:

- Sharepoint 2013 Standart On Premise
- Default result search page

When I query the search results page I get all the results correctly. When I got the second (or any other) page I get the following error:

> Missing list. The selected page contains a nonexistent list. It may have been deleted by another user.

Have anyone else seen it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The possible answer is here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/147238/reservation-of-resources-in-sharepoint-2013

Comment: I've seen it already. The cases are different. In mine I'm using the default Sharepoint search page. I've tried to create a new site in English, but I get the same behavior.